# Sidebar.jsx:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in firebase9 reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting this error

> Sidebar.jsx:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map').

I am using firebase version 9 and react version 18. I don't know why it is coming I read the firebase docs but still getting this error every time.

Sidebar.jsx

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
 import './Sidebar.css'
 import { Avatar, IconButton } from '@mui/material';
 import DonutLargeOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DonutLargeOutlined';
 import InsertCommentIcon from '@mui/icons-material/InsertComment';
 import MoreVertIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoreVert';
 import SearchOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SearchOutlined';
 import SidebarChat from '../SidebarChat/SidebarChat';
 import db from '../../firebase'
 import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore"

 const Sidebar = () => {
     const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([])

     useEffect(() => {
        const snapshot = collection(db, "rooms")
        const roomsRef = getDocs(snapshot)
        setRooms(roomsRef.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })))

     }, [])


     return (
         <div className='sidebar'>
             <div className="sidebar__header">
                 <Avatar src="/broken-image.jpg" />

                 <div className="sidebar__headerRight">
                     <IconButton>
                         <DonutLargeOutlinedIcon />
                     </IconButton>

                     <IconButton>
                         <InsertCommentIcon />
                     </IconButton>

                     <IconButton>
                         <MoreVertIcon />
                     </IconButton>
                 </div>
            </div>

            <div className="sidebar__search">
                <div className="sidebar__searchContainer">
                    <SearchOutlinedIcon />
                    <input type="text" placeholder='Serach or start a new chat' />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="sidebar__chat">
               <SidebarChat addNewChat />
               {rooms.map(room => (
                   <SidebarChat key={room.id} id={room.id} name={room.data.name} />
               ))}
             </div>
       </div>
   )
 }

 export default Sidebar
```

firebase.js

```
 import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
 import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"
 import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider  } from "firebase/auth"

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projected: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = getAuth(app)

const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider()

const db = getFirestore(app)

export { auth, googleProvider };

export default db;

<!---- Everything is good in my frebase file ----->
```

Comment: Add a console.log(roomsRef.docs) after const roomsRef = getDocs(snapshot)

Comment: getting undefined

Comment: Then something is wrong with your getDocs() function because it is not returning an array as you expected rather it is returning undefined and you are trying to access map on undefined, henceforth the error

Comment: when I use the try-catch block in my code only data is saved in firebase but not getting on the frontend. I don't know why is it coming, first time when I run my code It's giving me everything.But After sometimes I am getting map is undefined.

Comment: `getDocs` returns a `promise`. You need to use either `await`, either `.then`. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection

Comment: still the same error after using  .then

Comment: Please, update your code with the edits you made or edit your question with adding additional explanation about what you tried and code example

Answer (score 0):

```
  ##  Sidebar.jsx

  import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
  import './Sidebar.css'
  import { Avatar, IconButton } from '@mui/material';
  import DonutLargeOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons- 
  material/DonutLargeOutlined';
  import InsertCommentIcon from '@mui/icons-material/InsertComment';
  import MoreVertIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoreVert';
  import SearchOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SearchOutlined';
  import SidebarChat from '../SidebarChat/SidebarChat';
  import db from '../../firebase'
  import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore"



  const Sidebar = () => {
     const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([])

     useEffect(() => {

        <------Updated code ------------- >

        getDocs(collection(db, "rooms"))
        .then(snapshot => {
         setRooms(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, data: 
         doc.data() })))
         })
        .catch(error => console.log(error.message))

      <-------------------------------------------------->

     }, [])


     return (
         <div className='sidebar'>
             <div className="sidebar__header">
                 <Avatar src="/broken-image.jpg" />

                 <div className="sidebar__headerRight">
                     <IconButton>
                         <DonutLargeOutlinedIcon />
                     </IconButton>

                     <IconButton>
                         <InsertCommentIcon />
                     </IconButton>

                     <IconButton>
                         <MoreVertIcon />
                     </IconButton>
                 </div>
            </div>

            <div className="sidebar__search">
                <div className="sidebar__searchContainer">
                    <SearchOutlinedIcon />
                    <input type="text" placeholder='Serach or start a new 
                    chat' />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="sidebar__chat">
               <SidebarChat addNewChat />
               {rooms.map(room => (
                   <SidebarChat key={room.id} id={room.id} name= 
                    {room.data.name} />
                ))}
            </div>
       </div>
   )
 }

 export default Sidebar
```

Comment: This is the updated code. Now The issue has been resolved. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).